# My .htaccess works on the my main login page but subsequent redirects does not work

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi i am new to codeignitor my application works fine in my local host but when i bring it live server it gives me the below error
[Error after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWxKF.png)

My config file i have already set the base_url to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://diamondglass.com.sg//portal/';
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My .htaccess is in my portal folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

My index function in my project Controller

```
function index()
{
    $data['projects'] = $this->project_model->getAll();
    $data['users'] = $this->user_model->getAll();
    
    // set array of items in session for page
    $arraydata = array(
            'mainsection'  => 'Projects',
            'subsection'    => 'Projects'
    );

    $data['statuscount'] = $this->project_model->getStatusCount();
    
    $this->session->set_userdata($arraydata);
    $this->load->view('admin/project/index',$data);
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($this->session->userdata());
}
```

My Login Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->session->userdata('user'))
        redirect('admin/project');

    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
}
public function index()
{
    
    $this->load->view('login');
}

//To Verify Logins 
function verify()
{
    
    $this->load->model('user_model');

        
    /* Load form validation library */ 
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)  
    {  
        //model function  
        $this->load->model('user_model'); 
        $check = $this->user_model->validate();
        if($check)  
        {  
            $this->session->set_userdata('user','1');  
            $this->session->set_userdata('currentUser',$check);
             redirect('admin/project');  
        }  
        else  
        {  
             $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');  
             redirect('login');  
        }  
   }  
   else  
   {  
        //false  
        redirect('login');  
   }   

}

}
```

I have been searching the web high and low for a solution, but i can figure this out. I know it got to do with .htaccess but can't figure this out. can someone help

Comment: Why does your base URL contain a double slash?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put the IfModule tags every time. Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 http://diamondglass.com.sg/404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.html [L]
```

Make sure you have a custom 404 page

Comment: Hi Eminu

Thank you for the quick responds but i am afraid the error persist after the change of code and more over the layout of the landing login page went haywire

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your base_url has wrong (// after .sg)

Second, make sure your view-file is located at: ../Views/admin/project/index.php